# get_current_dir_name simple program cannot compile -> implicit declaration for library function

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gnu

I have a very simple program that I'm using to try to learn C better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", get_current_dir_name());
    return 0;
}
```

but the problem is that compiling this program thus:

```
gcc -o pushtob2 pushtob2.c -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu11  -static -Wextra -Wconversion
```

generates an error:

```
pushtob2.c: In function ‘main’:
pushtob2.c:8:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘get_current_dir_name’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("%s\n", get_current_dir_name());
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pushtob2.c:8:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%s\n", get_current_dir_name());
          ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          %d
```

I was told that `get_current_dir_name` should be defined within `unistd.h` from https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd

why isn't the compiler finding `get_current_dir_name` and not compiling?

Comment: Did you define `_GNU_SOURCE` as the man page instructs?

Comment: @Crowman yes, `_GNU_SOURCE` is the 3rd line in the program

Comment: Try defining it before including any of your headers.

Comment: @Crowman indeed, `_GNU_SOURCE` must be included first, that was the problem!

Comment: @Crowman if you can post your solution, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` (and feature test macros in general) before including any headers - i.e. not just the header containing the construct in question - so change this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

to this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```